# Pulling data from database to Asp.Net Datatable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

```
 <script>$(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetCategories", "Kategori")', //1- aksiyon adını alır. 2- Controller ismini alır.
                    method: 'GET',
                    success: function (data) {
                        // AJAX isteği başarılı olduğunda bu fonksiyon çalışır.

                        // subProcessTable adlı HTML elementini DataTable'a dönüştürüyor.
                        var table = $('#dataTable1').DataTable();

                        // Tabloyu temizleyip tekrar çiziyor.
                        table.clear().draw();

                        // Sunucudan gelen alt işlem listesini alıyor.
                        var categoriesList = data.categoriesList;

                        // Alt işlem listesini döngüye alıyor.
                        categoriesList.forEach(function (item) {
                            // Tabloya bir satır ekliyor.
                            table.row.add([
                                item.categoryName,
                                '<button>Edit</button>',
                                '<button>Delete</button>'
                            ]).draw();
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        toastr.error(data.message);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

I want to pull the data from the database into a datatable. But I couldn't understand what kind of problem there was in my code, I would be glad if you could help me.

Thanks

Comment: WHat does the url `@Url.Action("GetCategories", "Kategori")` actually return?. Check the returned data with the browser console. And maybe there could also be front-end errors? That is also visible in the console.